# Как проверить, является ли символ латинского алфавита гласной буквой?

Tags: java

Допустим, ввели строку. Нужно проверить (в цикле), является ли данный символ гласной буквой латинского алфавита. Есть ли какой-то аналог метода contains() для char[] ?

```
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        char[] line = reader.readLine().toCharArray();
        char[] vowels = new char[] {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};

        for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
        }
```

P.S. Понимаю, что можно сделать это с помощью двойного цикла, но мне важно время исполения.

Comment: Можно убрать `char[]` и проверять так: `"aeiou".indexOf(символ) != -1`